# How to show value in view when user click on image button.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show network value when user click myimage.I am new to rails i do not know how to show it.

Below is my index.html.erb file which render value when zone.Zone_id==network.zone_id.I want this value when user click myimage.

```
<% @zones.each do |zone| %>
<tr>
 <td><span onclick="networkrender(<%= zone.Zone_id%>);" id="myimage_<%=one.Zone_id%>">
     <%= image_tag("minus.gif")%></span></td>
 <td><span><input type="checkbox" /></span></td>
 <td><%=zone.Zone_name%></td><br />   
</tr>

<% @networks.each do |network| %>
  <% if(zone.Zone_id == network.zone_id)%>
  <tr class="trhideclass1">
   <td></td>
   <td><span><input type="checkbox" /></span></td>
   <td><%= network.network_name %></td>
   <td><%= network.local_tb_id %></td>
   <td><%= network.interconnect %></td>
   <td><%= network.interconnect_tb_id %></td>
   <td><%= network.tonegroup %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try making your question to explain more on what you are trying. <% link_to '<input type="button" name="sample" value="show">'.html_safe, network_index_path %>.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to go javascript/jQuery on this.

Either http://jqueryui.com/show/ or http://jqueryui.com/toggle/ will suit you depending on your needs.

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
     $("#myimage").click(function () {
        $(".trhideclass1").show("slow");
     });

  });
```

Comment: I want to show this value through jQuery how to show this value <% @networks.each do |network| %>
  <% if(zone.Zone_id == network.zone_id)%>
  <tr class="trhideclass1">
   <td></td>
   <td><span><input type="checkbox" /></span></td>
   <td><%= network.network_name %></td>
   <td><%= network.local_tb_id %></td>
   <td><%= network.interconnect %></td>
   <td><%= network.interconnect_tb_id %></td>
   <td><%= network.tonegroup %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %> i want to show this value